# how to show multiple progress bar while using tqdm and pandas in multiprocessing?

Tags: python, pandas, tqdm

the follwoing is my code, it does only show one progress bar at a time
`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from tqdm import tqdm
import multiprocessing as mp

def func2(message):
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.ones([10,100000]))
    tqdm.pandas(desc=f'job{message}')
    df = df.progress_apply(lambda col: col+5)
    print('job done, now caching')
    df.to_csv(f'df{message}.csv')
    print('caching done')
    print(df.columns)
    

def para2(func):
    with mp.Pool(10) as p:
         p.imap(func, [i for i in range(10)])
    print('para work done, now loading cache')
    ret_list = [pd.read_csv(f'df{i}.csv') for i in range(10)] 
    print(ret_list)
    return pd.concat(ret_list)
        
para2(func2)
```

`

how can i make all working cores show their own progress at the same time?